# I have a problem for enter float variable in cypher (i use python)

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher

i would like use "recherche_distance" function for calculate distance with neo4j.
I use cypher query and i had an error :

```
nosql: <V2_NoSqlDataAccess.NoSqlDataAccess object at 0x000001A283C95BE0>
<class 'float'>
<class 'float'>
lat = 45.438, longi = 4.3862
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Datascientest\neo4j\test_projet\test.py", line 9, in <module>
    result = nsql.recherche_distance(lat, longi)
  File "c:\Datascientest\neo4j\test_projet\V2_NoSqlDataAccess.py", line 49, in recherche_distance
    cypher_query = '''
KeyError: 'x '
```

This is my code :

```
from neo4j import GraphDatabase, basic_auth
import pandas as pd
import math



class Point:
    def __init__(self,longitude,latitude, lat, longi):
        self.longitude=longitude
        self.latitude=latitude
        self.lat=lat
        self.longi=longi


class NoSqlDataAccess:

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = GraphDatabase.driver('bolt://localhost:11003',auth=basic_auth("neo4j", "xxxx"))
    
    def close(self):
        self.driver.close()
   
    def create_localisation_line(tx,type, latitude, longitude, lieu,code_insee,id_datatourisme):
            query = "CREATE (n:Localisation {type: $type ,latitude: $latitude,longitude: $longitude, lieu: $lieu,code_insee: $code_insee,id_datatourisme: $id_datatourisme}) RETURN id(n) AS node_id"
            
            tx.run(query,type = type,latitude = latitude, longitude = longitude, lieu = lieu,code_insee=code_insee,id_datatourisme=id_datatourisme)
            

    def add_localisations(self,datagraph):
       with self.driver.session() as session:
            for i, row in datagraph.iterrows():
                #if i==100000:
                #    break
                #else:
                type = row['type']
                latitude = row['latitude']
                longitude = row['longitude']
                lieu = row['adresse']
                code_insee=row['code_insee']
                id_datatourisme=row['id']
                query = "CREATE (n:Localisation {type:"+str(row['type'])+",latitude:"+str(latitude)+",longitude: "+str(longitude)+", lieu: "+str(lieu)+",code_insee: "+str(code_insee)+",id_datatourisme:"+str(id_datatourisme)+"})"
                print(query)
                session.run(query)
       self.close()


    def recherche_distance(self, lat, longi):
        with self.driver.session() as session:
            cypher_query = '''
                MATCH (s1:Info)
                WITH point({x : toFloat(s1.latitude), y : toFloat(s1.longitude)}) AS p1, point({x:toFloat({lat}), y:toFloat({longi})}) AS p2, s1
                RETURN point.distance(p1,p2) AS Distance, s1.lieu AS Lieu ORDER BY Distance
                '''.format(lat=lat, longi=longi)
            print(f'Requête Cypher : {cypher_query}')
            result = session.run(cypher_query)
            print(f'Résultat de la requête : {result}')
            return result.fetch(5)
        self.close()
```

This is my second code for use query :
`

```
from V2_NoSqlDataAccess import NoSqlDataAccess
nsql = NoSqlDataAccess()
print('nosql:', nsql)
lat = 45.4380
print(type(lat))
longi = 4.3862
print(type(longi))
print(f'lat = {lat}, longi = {longi}')
result = nsql.recherche_distance(lat, longi)
print(result)
```

I think, i have a problem with the variable "lat" and "longi" i didn't find the solution.
I haven't error if i write lat and longi manually
Thank you for your help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the {} found in the query.  Use {{ and }} to escape {}, respectively.

```
 OLD: 
            WITH point({x : toFloat(s1.latitude), y : toFloat(s1.longitude)}) AS p1, point({x:toFloat({lat}), y:toFloat({longi})}) AS p2, s1

NEW: 
            WITH point({{x: toFloat(s1.latitude), y: toFloat(s1.longitude)}}) AS p1, point({{x: toFloat({lat}), y: toFloat({longi})}}) AS p2, s1
```

This is because python format string function "thinks" that you are passing a parameter named x. But this is actually a part of the cypher query.

Comment: It's ok for KeyError : X but actualy, i've a same error for 'lat'.
````
cypher_query = '''
                MATCH (s1:Info)
                WITH point({{x: toFloat(s1.latitude), y: toFloat(s1.longitude)}}) AS p1, point({{x: toFloat({lat}), y: toFloat({longi})}}) AS p2, s1
                RETURN point.distance(p1,p2) AS Distance, s1.lieu AS Lieu ORDER BY Distance
                '''.format(lat, longi)
````
RESULT :
    cypher_query = '''
KeyError: "lat"

Comment: The script works for me when I tested it (although no records found) BUT it is NOT getting a syntax or runtime error.

Comment: You have a python typo error. It should be format(lat=lat, rather than format(lat,

Comment: You are true. it's ok. Thank you so much !!

Comment: Glad that it worked for you. HNY!